CiviPlus/Compuco Dashboard?
Have seen some heavy-customised Drupal theme for CiviCRM Dashboard at demo.civiplus.net
Don't think it's available as a FOSS, just wondering what would be a cost/time-frame of building something similar for D11. An advice from crystal ball owners please?

